# C++ Pass parameter types with member pointer to template

Tags: c++, templates, function-pointers, variadic-templates

I'm trying to convert members of `SomeStruct` to non-const `void(*)()`'s. For that, I use a class called `Base` that has a template member function `nc()` that converts the member pointer to a non-const pointer by converting itself: `(static_cast<Derived *>(this)->*ptr)()`.

Problem: I also need this to work with `void`s receiving parameters (see second line of `main()`). I'm new to parameter packing/unpacking and forwarding, so any help would be appreciated!

Here is my code so far (updated to more minimal example):

```
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>

template <typename Derived> 
struct Base
{
    template <void (Derived::*ptr)() const>     // should also take arbitrary amount
    void nc()                                   // of params
    {
        (static_cast<Derived *>(this)->*ptr)();
    }
};

struct SomeStruct: public Base<SomeStruct>
{
    void exit() const;
    void takesParam(int num);
};

inline void SomeStruct::exit() const               
{
}

inline void SomeStruct::takesParam(int num)
{
}

int main()
{
    auto ptr1 = &Base<SomeStruct>::nc<&SomeStruct::exit>;    // works
    //auto ptr2 = &Base<SomeStruct>::nc<&SomeStruct::takesParam>; // error
}
```

and the error message I get when compiling with `g++-10` (unused variable can be ignored ofc):

```
main.cc: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cc:31:36: error: unable to deduce ‘auto’ from ‘& nc<&SomeStruct::takesParam>’
   31 |     auto ptr2 = &Base<SomeStruct>::nc<&SomeStruct::takesParam>;
      |                                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
main.cc:31:36: note:   couldn’t deduce template parameter ‘auto’
main.cc:30:10: warning: unused variable ‘ptr1’ [-Wunused-variable]
   30 |     auto ptr1 = &Base<SomeStruct>::nc<&SomeStruct::exit>;    // works
      |          ^~~~
```

Comment: @newbie it is a definition of an array to member functions, not a member function. Hence, you'd only need to write a comma in between the array elements.

Comment: so why did you write it like a function? also the type of ```&CPU::takesParam``` is different from ```&CPU::exit```. one of them has no argument as a function```inline void CPU::exit() const``` and the other one has an ```int``` as an argument as a function ```inline void CPU::takesParam(int num)```

Comment: @newbie - The OP didn't "write it as a function". They defined an array of function pointers using C++'s verbose declarator syntax. As for everything else you noted... that's the gist of the question!

Comment: Not only they can't be in a same array but also ```nc``` itself is defined like ```template <void (Derived::*ptr)() const>
    void nc();``` which mean its template argument ```<void (Derived::*ptr)() const>```should only be a member functions which has no arguments

Comment: @newbie see StoryTeller's comment. It's indeed that what I'm looking for; the template should take void function pointers with and without parameters.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica could you please give me a reference so I can read more about  C++'s verbose declarator syntax.

Comment: @newbie - I haven't ever seen a good description of the grammar to point at. But there are some heuristics people find useful. The "spiral rule" specifically (I can't find my original reference for it). There's https://cdecl.org/ which turns declarators into worded descriptions. And [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pointer#Pointers_to_functions) contains a table of some common brain teasers.

Answer (score 1):

I am not exactly sure of what you are trying to achieve but since in the the definition of `nc` you have:

```
    template <void (Derived::*ptr)() const>
    void nc();
```

you can not refer to `nc` whit different type of member function which should be like `void (Derived::*ptr)() const`.
But you simply can add another overload like :

```
    template <void (Derived::*ptr)(int)>
    void nc();
```

which then solves your problem and then you can have both:

```
void (CPU::*CPU::s_opcode[])() =
{
    &Base<CPU>::nc<&CPU::exit>,       // accepting const works
    &Base<CPU>::nc<&CPU::takesParam>  // does not work
};
```

you can define the this overload like:

```
template <typename Derived>
template <void (Derived::*ptr)(int) >
void Base<Derived>::nc()                
{                                       
    (static_cast<Derived *>(this)->*ptr)(0);
}
```

Comment: thank you very much for the answer! That would be a possibility, but unfortunately I'm required to get a member pointer with an arbitrary amount of params. I changed my example to leave out the array, maybe that clears things up a bit.